# VS2010 database project deploy rebuilds every table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have recently created a database project in VS2010 for an existing SQL Server 2008 R2 DB. I have updated 1 table out of 11 by adding 3 new columns to the end. I then updated 4 views that referred to that table.

I then tried a Build/Deploy with it only generating a script.

I have inspected the script and for every single table in the DB, it has generated code that will create a temp version of each table, copy the data from the existing table, drop the original and rename the copy.

I saw the posting on here where it insisted on rebuilding the table for dropped columns and I tried setting the IgnoreColumnOrder but it didn't make any difference. It didn't seem relevant to my situation, anyway, so I wasn't surprised.

I created my DB project by getting the DBA to give me a fully scripted version of Production, built that DB on my PC version of SQL Server and then created my initial project from that. I don't think that would make any difference and I have compared the project definition of the tables to the target Dev DB and they are the same.

I have "Always recreate database" unticked and "Block incremental deployment if data loss might occur" ticked. Don't suppose they have anything to do with my issue?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried doing a schema compare? You could have a collation difference or some other subtle difference that's resulting in a rebuild. That could also show you more details about what's actually different.  You may also consider trying an SSDT project (very similar in concept to the VS2010 DB Projects) to see if that is any different.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately last night I decided as a workaround to save the data, allowed the database to be recreated and then reloaded the data so I can no longer find the cause. I did try the schema compare against the Systest environment but that's saying "Skip" on most tables so whatever the issue was, I can no longer find out. Yours is a useful tip for the future. I don't think I can install SSDT. Aren't they the ones that come with SQL Server 2012? My machine is very shut down and I'm can't install anything outside the list of approved software.

Comment: You may want to chat with the powers that be about trying SSDT. I've found the functionality quite a bit better than VS DB Projects in most cases. I think it can run out of the VS2010 shell, though there are options to use VS2012 and VS2013 shells. Can see more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/

Answer (score 2):

I found a backup of the database and as per Peter's suggestion, ran a Schema Compare. The difference turned out to be that the target DB had PAGE compression on most of the tables but that was not in the project definition.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. Those are some of the easiest things to miss.